# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'batch- int:remote-chunking-slave'

Tags: spring-batch

sorry if this question has been already answered, I'm trying to build spring batch with remote chunking and a have an error with "cvc-complex-type.2.4.c" - I find so many answer cvc-complex-type.2.4.c:... but none of it say about "batch-  int:remote-chunking-slave"  about So here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:batch-int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration/spring-batch-integration.xsd">

    <batch-int:remote-chunking-slave id="remote-chunking-slave" input-channel="requests" output-channel="replies"
                                     item-processor="itemProcessor" item-writer="itemWriter"/>


    <bean id="itemProcessor" class="io.spring.remotechunkingslave.processor.ImageProcessor">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${unprocessed.images.dir}"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="200"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="150"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="itemWriter" class="io.spring.remotechunkingslave.writer.ImageWriter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${processed.images.dir}"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="jpg"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And any have error in:

```
<batch-int:remote-chunking-slave id="remote-chunking-slave" input-channel="requests" output-channel="replies"
                                     item-processor="itemProcessor" item-writer="itemWriter"/>
```

Can I get any advice on what's happening here?

Comment: What version are you using?  The remote-chunking-slave namespace support is in the latest snapshots only (not in a released version).

Comment: Thank for your advice, I'm using spring batch version : 3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. I'm a beginner in spring batch, so can you give an example about spring batch remote chunking

Comment: I already fix this  issue, thank for your support